# forward declaration and Cast incomplete type C++

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

I have issues about forward declaration .

```
namespace downloader {
class IHttpThreadCallback ;
class MemoryHttpRequest ;
```

}

when I cast

```
auto responseHttpRequest = dynamic_cast<downloader::MemoryHttpRequest*>(m_callback);
```

It show warning incomplete type . How should I try , please suggest to me .

beside that I try to include class , but it not work  and I think it not good idea . Thank you very much

Comment: You need to include the class definition.

Comment: Forward declarations of classes and structures only tell the compiler that the class or structure exist, but to use the class or structure you need the full definition.

Comment: Why do you think including the class is a bad idea? (And what did not work)?

Comment: Header files should have the forward declaration of pointers to objects that are private/protected.  You then include the headers for those objects in your c++ file.  All other objects should just have the header file with that class included.

Comment: sorry about feedback late , in my situation , the class which I need is defined in .cpp file , I don't know exactly why they do that .  IHttpThreadCallback is inherited from MemoryHttpRequest .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It show warning incomplete type . How should I try , please suggest to me.

To use `dynamic_cast`, the type must be complete. Solution: include the definition.

> beside that I try to include class , but it not work and I think it not good idea .

Including the class definition is not only a good idea, but mandatory if you need to use `dynamic_cast`. In this case, using a forward declaration is not a solution to your problem.

> in my situation , the class which I need is defined in .cpp file

In that case, you cannot downcast into that type - unless you move the class definition into a header that you include.

Comment: the answer is  so clear  , In my situation , I need to maintain the current source code . They use forward declaration for this case . thanks you

Answer (score 2):

dynamic_cast uses the vtable to interrogate and navigate the class hierarchy. it also needs to know the class content/layout in order to  calculate offsets. that is why the compiler needs to know the class definition. static_cast needs to have a relationship between the classes.

if you are sure about the return value and are happy to avoid the runtime/type check then you might consider using a reinterpret_cast.

otherwise you will need to include the definition.

I put an example together

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

namespace n {
  class A;
  class B;

  n::A* f();
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, n::A& a);
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, n::B& b);

int main()
{
  n::A* a(n::f());
  n::B* b=reinterpret_cast<n::B*>(n::f());

  std::cerr << "a: " << *a << std::endl;
  std::cerr << "b: " << *b << std::endl;
}

namespace n {
  class A
  {};

  class B: public A
  {};

  n::A* f() {
    return new A();
  }  
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, n::A& a) {
  os << "in A";
  return os;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, n::B& b) {
  os << "in B";
  return os;
}
```

Comment: Static downcasting also requires the definition.